# Meaning of 幼くして and 醒めている

Tags: meaning, words

> しかし、**幼くして**彼女はどこか**醒めている**ところがあり、真里亞が上機嫌に魔法のことを語るのを聞きながら、そんなものが本当にあるわけがないとも思っていた。

Why is it 幼くして, not 幼い彼女は・・・ ? What about 醒める here ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll talk about 「醒{さ}めている」 first.  In this context, it means "***(very) realistic***" or "level-headed".  The little girl is not dreamy as one might tend to expect.

Moving on to 「幼{おさな}くして」...

It means "***at a tender/early age***" or more plainly, "for her age" in this context.  I tried to explain the nuance of 「～～にして」 here:

[Difference between 六歳にして and 六歳で](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/53725/difference-between-%e5%85%ad%e6%ad%b3%e3%81%ab%e3%81%97%e3%81%a6-and-%e5%85%ad%e6%ad%b3%e3%81%a7)

> Why is it 幼くして, not 幼い彼女は・・・ ?

Because the author wants to imply that it is rather rare for such a young girl to be 醒めている.

If one used 「幼い彼女は」, it would make it sound as if it were quite normal for very young girls to be 醒めている.